# Linux expression to get concrete file when you know only it name and it previous folder

Tags: linux

if I am in folder 'a'
and now I want to get some file which by this way

> more ./* ... */* ... */new_folder/doc.txt

how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for it:

```
find . -name "doc.txt" -exec more {} \;
```

To only see files in particular sub-directory:

```
find . -wholename "*new_dir/doc.txt" -exec more {} \;
find . -wholename "*/some_dir/*/some_other_dir/*/doc.txt" -exec more {} \;
```

Alternatively, you can use grep:

```
find . -name "doc.txt" | grep "new_dir" | xargs more
```

Comment: ok but, what if i need the file which exist directly after new_folder/

Comment: and last one. if i have `new_dir/*****/doc.txt`. how get it by find command and -wholename?

Comment: See above. You can put any combination of sub directories, the portions of the path you don't know, or you don't care about, you can substitute with wildcards.